# TexLive Version outdated and unsupported by repositories

Tags: texlive

I recently upgraded my Linux Distribution to Ubuntu 14.04 and received the following error when I tried installing a package using tlmgr:

> (running on Debian, switching to user mode!) tlmgr: The TeX Live
>   versions supported by the repository
>   http://ctan.uib.no/systems/texlive/tlnet   (2014--2014) do not include
>   the version of the local installation   (2013).

I thus upgraded my TexLive Distribution to 2014 using `install-tl` as described here: http://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html

When I now execute `tlmgr update --self`, I receive the same error as above! tex --version yields this:

> TeX 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)  kpathsea version 6.1.1 Copyright
>   2013 D.E. Knuth.

The version seems to be unchanged! What is this noob doing wrong?

Comment: Did you set the according `$PATH` in your `.profile` (or whereever you prefer)?

Comment: Yup. echo $PATH yields /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-linux/

Answer (score 5):

You have 2 versions of TeX Live installed: one installed with `install-tl` and one installed using Debian's package manager. The latter is first in `PATH`. You should do two things. First, your `PATH` should have the `texlive` bit first. (I would do this so it does not affect root's PATH.) Second, you should get rid of the Debian installation to avoid confusion and install a dummy package to keep your package manager happy. There is a full explanation in the [question on installing vanilla TL from upstream on Debian/Ubuntu systems](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu).

Comment: I created the fake packages using equivs and modified $PATH. tex --version yields TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2014) kpathsea version 6.2.0 Copyright 2014 D.E. Knuth.
echo $PATH yields /opt/texbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games. YET, when I try sudo tlmgr install <package>, I get the same error as above : lmgr: The TeX Live versions supported by the repository http://ctan.uib.no/systems/texlive/tlnet (2014--2014) do not include the version of the local installation (2013).!!!

Comment: Also, I don't think I'm looking for the other TeXLive installation in the right place. I can't find it in /usr/local/texlive. Have I really succeeded in removing it then?

Comment: @KurtVonnegut So I think you have not succeeded in removing Debian's TL. Try searching your installed packages in your package manager for `texlive` to find the names of the packages you need to remove. `sudo` may be using a different `PATH`. Try specifying the full path to `tlmgr`.